# Generalisation of Nested For loop in C

Tags: c, loops, dynamic-programming

I am writing a c program which will take input some n characters (in a string)  and write all possible combination of the n characters ( comprising if 1 digit to n letter word)

Simply to make a word list file from the string characters.

So I understand it as

1st letter : range 0 to n
2nd letter: range 0 to n
.   .
.   .
.   .
nth letter : range 0 to n

Clearly I have to write maximum  "n" nested loops which is not generalized in normal
I want to make the nested for loop operation generalised.
Is there any techniques ?

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is your friend. To write all possible combinations of a string of six letters, write the six letters in sequence, then write all the possible suffixes, which is the same problem, with 5 letter strings. To write all possible combinations of a string of one letter, write the letter (termination condition).